# Trying relational division on oracle (right parenthesis missing?)

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

I'm trying to execute the following query in Oracle:

```
SELECT c.id_cliente, c.nombre_cliente, c.apellidos_cliente
FROM cliente c
WHERE not exists (SELECT f.id_finca
       FROM finca f
       WHERE f.habitaciones = 3
       EXCEPT
       SELECT v.id_fincas
       FROM visitas v
       WHERE v.id_cliente = c.id_cliente)
```

But I am getting the error "missing right parenthesis".

The parenthesis are well-balanced, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MINUS` instead of `EXCEPT`.

```
SELECT c.id_cliente, 
       c.nombre_cliente, 
       c.apellidos_cliente 
FROM   cliente c 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT f.id_finca 
                   FROM   finca f 
                   WHERE  f.habitaciones = 3 
                   MINUS
                   SELECT v.id_fincas 
                   FROM   visitas v 
                   WHERE  v.id_cliente = c.id_cliente)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no operator `EXCEPT` in Oracle. Use `MINUS` instead of it.

Additionally, your query seems weird: better try to make it with two `not exists`, I think it can give some performance.